# xslt calculating insurance writeoff not working

Tags: xslt

I am trying to calculate the contractual write off for medical insurance but the calculation doesn't seem to be working.  For example, I need to take the value of the charge attribute on the `<charge>` tag and subtract the value of the amount attribute on the `<adjustment>` tag but only when the group and code attributes on the `<adjustment>` tag are: group ='CO' and code = '45' or '385'

I was able to get everything but the calculations working.  I've tried looking at several answers on this forum but am obviously missing something.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my XML (simplified):

```
<result check_number="05173408" ...>
    <claim ... total_charge="720" total_paid="43">
        <charge charge="200">
            <adjustment amount="125" code="45" group="CO" />
            <adjustment amount="35" code="385" group="CO" />
            <adjustment amount="20" code="3" group="PR" />
        </charge>
        <charge charge="70">
            <adjustment amount="70" code="204" group="PR" />
        </charge>
        <charge charge="300">
            <adjustment amount="273" code="45" group="CO" />
            <adjustment amount="15" code="3" group="PR" />
        </charge>
        <charge charge="150">
            <adjustment amount="139" code="45" group="CO" />
        </charge>
    </claim>
</result>
```

Here is my xslt to date:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- maps to the beginning result tag -->
        <xsl:for-each select="/result/claim/charge">
        <!-- amount allowed by the insurance for line item -->
            <COL>
                <DATA>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="adjustment" mode="calcAdjTotal" >
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                </DATA>
            </COL>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- Template created to test Parfait's suggestion   -->
        <xsl:template match="adjustment" mode="calcAdjTotal" >
            <xsl:variable name="condition" select="adjustment[@group='CO' and (@code='45' or @code='385')]"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="../@charge - sum($condition/@amount)" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my output: (updated output)

```
<COL>
    </DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
    </DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
    </DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
    </DATA>
</COL>
```

Here's what I want to get:

```
<COL>
    <DATA>
        40
    </DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
    <DATA>
    </DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
    <DATA>
        27
    </DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
    <DATA>
        11
    </DATA>
</COL>
```

The format will then be used to import data into Filemaker.

Comment: Could you explain the required logic in words, please? It is difficult to deduce it from the example or from non-working code. If I deduct the adjustments that meet your criteria from the charge, I get {40, 70, 27, 11}. You show {40, , 27, 11}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider wrapping your conditional equation in an `<xsl:if>`. Additionally, you can do so with a variable storing the conditional value to avoid repetition:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ROOT>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </ROOT>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="charge">
    <xsl:variable name="condition" select="adjustment[(@code='45' or @code='385') and @group='CO']"/>        
    <COL>
      <DATA>
        <xsl:if test="$condition">            
          <xsl:value-of select="@charge - sum($condition/@amount)"/>            
        </xsl:if>
      </DATA>
    </COL>    
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: @michael.hor257k and Parfait, thanks for your help! Parfait's solution worked.  I modified the xslt some in that I started from the adjustment tag and not the charge tag but it created the desired result.  I set my select on the variable = "@code='45' or '385'" and my value-of select="../@charge - sum(@amount)".  I was trying to use recursion when I didn't need to.  Thanks again.

Comment: I did some more testing and your xml only works for one amount attribute and I need it to work for multiple attributes.  See the top group of <adjustment> tags in my example xml.

Comment: Answer here conditionally aggregates all `adjustment` nodes. Are you saying 40 is not correct for first `charge` group: 200 - (125 + 35) = 40? Please post the XML where this is not the case.

Comment: yes it is correct but it didn't work that way in my test.  Maybe it is the way I call the template.  I will look at my code again.  If it is still a problem I will post my xslt.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Parfait, I updated the xslt above to reflect my code with your template.  I think the problem has something to do with you using select="*" and me using select="/" and for each select="/result/claim/charge".

Comment: I avoid the `xsl:for-each`. If original XML looks like your posted one, then entire stylesheet here should work for desired outcome. No need to change it.

Comment: Just to follow up on this.  I ended up rewriting my xslt to match the format of yours (Parfait) and mine now works.  That is, I rewrote it and used templates instead of for loops and was able to use your template "charge".  It was a great learning experience.  I am now beginning to understand the value of templates.  Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Wow! Good to finally hear from you months later. If my answer helped, please do check it to confirm resolution of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing (!) you want something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <RESULT>
        <xsl:for-each select="claim/charge">
            <ROW>
                <COL>
                    <DATA>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@charge - sum(adjustment[@group='CO' and (@code='45' or @code='385')]/@amount)" />
                    </DATA>
                </COL>
            </ROW>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </RESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESULT>
   <ROW>
      <COL>
         <DATA>40</DATA>
      </COL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <COL>
         <DATA>70</DATA>
      </COL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <COL>
         <DATA>27</DATA>
      </COL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <COL>
         <DATA>11</DATA>
      </COL>
   </ROW>
</RESULT>
```

This assumes you want to create a record (with one field) for each `charge`.

Note that this is not valid FileMaker XML syntax.

---

***-- edited in response to clarifications in comments: --***

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <RESULT>
        <xsl:for-each select="claim/charge[adjustment[not(@group='PR')]]">
            <ROW>
                <COL>
                    <DATA>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@charge - sum(adjustment[not(@group='PR')]/@amount)" />
                    </DATA>
                </COL>
            </ROW>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </RESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESULT>
   <ROW>
      <COL>
         <DATA>40</DATA>
      </COL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <COL>
         <DATA>27</DATA>
      </COL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <COL>
         <DATA>11</DATA>
      </COL>
   </ROW>
</RESULT>
```

Comment: I need to find all the adjustment tags with with group='CO' and code='45' or '385'.  Then subtract the amount on the amount attribute from the amount on the charge attribute of the charge tag.

So, I need to exclude adjustment tags with group='PR' from the output.

Ultimately I need, 200-125-35=40, an empty tag or 0, 300-273=27 and 150-139=11 as output for the tags.

Comment: @JMW Why an empty tag or 0 and not 70  - 0 = 70?

Comment: Yes, I know it is not valid Filemaker XML syntax.  I have a much larger xslt that creates valid Filemaker XML.  This is just a portion of it.  I am trying to get help figuring out why my mathematical calculations don't work.

Comment: @michael.kor257k, I need exactly what I show {40, ,27,11}.  The amount 70 is attached to a group='PR' and should be filtered out.  I'm thinking that means I need a blank tag but 0 would work too.  I am trying to find the amount the insurance company is contractually obligated to pay.

Comment: @JMW I am sorry, but you will need to spell out the **logic** for me, not just show me the result.The only difference I see is that the second `charge` has **only** adjustments of `group="PR"`. Or doesn't have any adjustments where group ='CO' and code = '45' or '385' - you seem to imply these tests are mutually exclusive. -- I am also puzzled why you need an empty or 0 result - why not remove such record from the result altogether?

Comment: @michael.kor257k, the answer to your question.  The output will be imported into different fields in Filemaker.  It is my experience that when importing Filemaker can't deal with missing tags so the tag must exist, must be in a specific order and must be empty.  Since it is financial data I could also put a 0 instead of leave the tag empty to show that there is no money from the insurance company for that particular charge.  That is why the blank or 0.

Comment: @michael.kor257k, loop through charge tags, under each charge tag loop through adjustment tags. For each adjustment tag subtract the value in the amount attribute on the adjustment tag from the value in the parent charge attribute.  Only subtract amounts whose group is 'CO' and code is '45' or '385'.  If there is no adjustment tag with group 'CO' and code '45' or '385' create an empty tag.  They are totally different amounts on an invoice.  Yes, they are mutually exclusive.  The amounts in the 'CO' group belong to the insurance company and the amounts in the 'PR' group belong to a patient.

Comment: IMHO, you need to create a **record** for each charge. Otherwise you would have to know in advance how many charges there will be and dedicate a field to each - which would make for poor DB structure, even if possible.

Comment: @michael.kor257k, I am trying to use the existing database structure and use the xslt to make the information conform to the current database structure.  Each charge is associated with a line item on an invoice.  Each line-item is a record.  I have a field for each charge but I only have one field for the contractual obligation.  This is where the problem comes in.  Usually there is only one adjustment but there can be two.

Comment: Well, then remove the predicate from the `xsl:for-each` and make it a condition for outputting the value (similar to shown in Parfait's answer). It's really a trivial adjustment.